# TSQL select a field i'm also counting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I'm trying to count the number of distinct values in field D, grouped by fields A, B, and C. If the count returns 1, I would like to know what the value of D is.

For example:

```
SELECT A, B, C, COUNT(D) AS D_COUNT
FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE
GROUP BY A, B, C
HAVING COUNT(D) = 1
```

It's been a while since I've done SQL, and I've been around and around on this, and I'm convinced that there's probably something pretty simple and obvious I'm overlooking. For instance, I've tried several joins to the same table, but I keep running into the problem that 'D' is not contained in an aggregate or group by.. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As there is exactly one non `NULL` value of `D` in each group you can just use either `MAX` or `MIN` to see what that value is.

```
SELECT A,
       B,
       C,
       COUNT(D) AS D_COUNT,
       MAX(D)   AS D
FROM   EXAMPLE_TABLE
GROUP  BY A,
          B,
          C
HAVING COUNT(D) = 1
```

A more general answer to this question that works for `COUNT(D) = @N` would use windowed aggregates. e.g.

```
;WITH T
     AS (SELECT A,
                B,
                C,
                D,
                COUNT(D) OVER (PARTITION BY A, B, C) AS D_COUNT
         FROM   EXAMPLE_TABLE)
SELECT *
FROM   T
WHERE  D_COUNT = @N
```

Comment: God, I would've never thought of that. Much better than my mess of joins. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT A, B, C, MAX(D) AS D, COUNT(D) AS D_COUNT
FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE
GROUP BY A, B, C
HAVING COUNT(D) = 1
```